# Xcode 4.3 - Standard/Retina navigation bar icons

Tags: ios, xcode, retina-display

Using the storyboard interface, you can only choose one icon to represent the button. What do you do if you want to support the 2x retina and the standard icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you choose an image you need to have it in double resolution with the @2x name for ex. button.png and button@2x.png - you choose button.png in the interface builder, but the system will automatically pickup @2x image if run on retina display.